# oracle spool have any settings to remove default lst extension?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

In oracle spool, if we not specify the spool file extension, we get "`file.lst`", any settings to get `file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that seems not possible. The documentation says

> If you do not specify an extension, SPOOL uses a default extension
> (LST or LIS on most systems). The extension is not appended to system
> files such as /dev/null and /dev/stderr.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SPOOL.html#GUID-61492052-ECCB-45C8-AF94-AB9794C60BEA

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Just specify the fully qualified name:

```
spool myfile.txt
```

Comment: which I mean is to get a file without any extension, just ```myfile```

Comment: No way that I've found. Why would you even want to have a file without an extension?